# Differentiating the minimizers of parametrized convex functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be strongly convex in the first argument, and smooth in the second. Consider
$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
x_*(y) = \argmin_x f(x, y)\,.
$$
**Can we somehow compute $\frac{dx_*}{dy}$ at a point $y$ without explicity computing the function $x_*$?**

Whenever $f$ is also smooth in $x$, we have
$$
0=\frac{d}{dy}\frac{\partial f(x_*,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}\frac{dx_*}{dy} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{dx_*}{dy} = -\left( \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} \right)^{-1}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}   \,.
$$
It would be nice to have something like this when $f$ doesn't have this additional regularity.

---

Just to provide an illustration:
What would be a good approach for the following example?

$$ f(x,y) = |x-y|^2 + |x|\,. $$

The explicit solutions are
$$
x_*(y) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }y\in(-\frac12,\frac12) \\
y - \frac12 & \text{if }y\ge\frac12 \\
y + \frac12 & \text{if }y\le-\frac12
\end{cases}\,,
\qquad
\frac{d x_*}{dy} = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }y\in(-\frac12,\frac12) \\
+1 & \text{if }y>\frac12 \\
-1 & \text{if }y<-\frac12
\end{cases}\,.
$$

Comment: Question : would you not ask if $x_{*}$ is differentiable first? Or do you know a result which guarantees it here? Certainly the well-definition is guaranteed by strong convexity.

Comment: Ah, I see : you ask only for a.e. differentiability, or in better words, a weak derivative, since in your example, differentiability is lost at $\pm \frac12$. We may be able to do something here.

Comment: You are right. That is how the question was intended. A first guess might be that the given formula holds wherever second x-derivatives of f exist, and that $dx_*/dy=0$ elsewhere (since the second derivative is "infinite" in a sense). Could that be true? But then a follow-up question would be how this generalizes to functions $f:\mathbb R^m\times\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$, because that is what I'm really interested in.

Comment: Ah,Klaas, I will have to see that. The point is, the kind of derivative you seek is a "weak" derivative, which you can read about. We can probably make statements on the weak derivative though . I will first suggest you look through some usual "derivative of maximum arguments", I believe there are some theorems that guarantee this.

Comment: Hi Klaas, I found [this document](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~sgould/papers/argmin-TR-2016.pdf) while looking for some help. It might contain something useful. Would you be ok if I tried to make something out of what is written here?

Comment: Closely related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_theorem

Comment: @TeresaLisbon In your link, assume "f be a continuous function with first and second derivatives"?

Comment: @RiverLi Very poorly written document, I attached it only because I thought I could make something of what was going on there, or if somebody else could it seemed related. I could not, but I decided not to remove the comment. The envelope theorem attached by Yuval makes far more sense to analyse. But I think we are looking for a *weak* derivative here, so all arguments need to be tailored that way. Unfortunately most results are for classical derivatives, OP's example does not have that characteristic.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks. Your link is helpful for related reading.

Comment: @RiverLi You are welcome. Let me tell you, however, that I am still so surprised that there is no context on weak derivatives of the maximum. I cannot underestimate what a field day optimal control theorists would have if such a statement was available! For starters, they could stop assuming regularity of initial conditions and even potentially of operators involved. This could be a good research topic for someone even at the undergraduate or graduate level!